# How does one make a proper static flowfram letterhead?

Tags: positioning, letterhead

Using the `flowfram` package, I have created a two page document where on the first page there is only one column and on the second page there are two columns. What I am trying to do now is create a static letterhead that appears at the top of each page. Below is the markup I have so far, but for some reason the letterhead is only appearing at the top of the second page and is constrained to the width of the second column.

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}

% Column 1, Page 1
\onecolumnStopinarea[1]{0.1\textheight}{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

% Column 1, Page 2+
\onecolumnStopinarea[>1]{0.1\textheight}{0.35\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

% Column 2, Page 2+
\onecolumnStopinarea[>1]{0.1\textheight}{0.6\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}

% Static Header
\setstaticframe{all}{label={header}, backcolor=myred, textcolor=white}
```

Document:

```
\begin{staticcontents*}{header}
\begin{center}
Letterhead
\end{center}
\end{staticcontents*}

\section{Column 1 on Page 1}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\section{Column 1 on Page 2}
\lipsum[1]

\framebreak

\section{Column 2 on Page 2}
\lipsum[1]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It would be better to combine your code fragments into a complete compilable document (as in my answer.)  E.g. `myred` is undefined (and not necessary for the example.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry, I will pay more attention to my examples in the future. Thank you for overlooking my mistakes and helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new static frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}

% Column 1, Page 1
\onecolumnStopinarea[1]{0.1\textheight}{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

% Column 1, Page 2+
\onecolumnStopinarea[>1]{0.1\textheight}{0.35\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

% Column 2, Page 2+
\onecolumnStopinarea[>1]{0.1\textheight}{0.6\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}

\newstaticframe{\textwidth}{.5in}{0pt}{.9\textheight}[header]
% Static Header
\setstaticframe{all}{label={header}, backcolor=red, textcolor=white}

\begin{document}
\begin{staticcontents*}{header}
\begin{center}
Letterhead
\end{center}
\end{staticcontents*}

\section{Column 1 on Page 1}
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\section{Column 1 on Page 2}
\lipsum[1]

\framebreak

\section{Column 2 on Page 2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Oh, duh! I feel silly now. Thanks for helping me.